# Managing Net TCP Port Sharing Configuration through Group Policy

Tags: wcf, windows-server, system-administration, group-policy, tcpportsharing

Our organization has an application infrastructure that consists of many WCF services deployed over many different servers on our network.  We'd like to move towards using the Net TCP Port Sharing service so that we can remove the need to assign a particular port for a particular service.  Enabling the service is easy, but the issue we have is allowing custom service users to access the service.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702669.aspx), services that run under an identity other than the defaults have to be added via the SMSvcHost.exe.config file in the .NET framework directory.  We're not entirely comfortable with the idea of having to individually modify this config file for every machine we want to enable port sharing on, is there a way that access and configuration for this service could be controlled through Group Policy or some other centralized means?